# How to create an image overlay which match the size of the image?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create an overlay above an image, which should match the size of the image **no matter which size** I give the Container.

This is my code I tried so far.

```dart
Container(
                     width: double.infinity,
                     height: double.infinity,
                     color: Colors.red,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Image.memory(
                              snapshot.data!,
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            ),
                            Positioned.fill(
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

This results to this image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL3Ig.png)
I expect that the grey overlay matches the size of the image.

Comment: wrap `Image.memory` with 'ColorFiltered' widget

Answer (score 1):

Move the `Stack` into a `FittedBox`:

```dart
Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: FittedBox(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      'images/default.png',
                    ),
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                        child: const Center(
                          child: Text('Overlay'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Give your Stack a **fit: Stackfit.expand**, so it expands to the Container size.

If this doesn't work you can try it with a BoxDecoration - found here https://medium.com/ariel-mejia-dev/make-an-image-with-opacity-layer-in-flutter-fca77e453731

```
decoration:
BoxDecoration(
  color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
  image: new DecorationImage(
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    colorFilter: 
      ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), 
      BlendMode.dstATop),
    image: new NetworkImage(
      'http://www.server.com/image.jpg',
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Nothing changes except that the image moved to the center.

Comment: Strange, i tried it on dartpad and it worked. Try the second option with a BoxDecoration, set it to your Conainer.